# hibernate 4.3.5 with Jboss 6.3 eap

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, jboss

when i use hibernat 4.3.5 with jboss 6.3 eap and try to start jboss, i get the following exception

```
Failed to define class org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform in Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform (Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)))
```

bellow is full stack trace exception

```
13:13:19,533 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
13:13:19,824 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final
13:13:19,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-4) starting
13:13:20,916 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) Failed to define class org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform in Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform (Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.injectJtaManager(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.loadPersistenceAdapterModule(PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.java:117) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.subsystem.JPAExtension.initialize(JPAExtension.java:110) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:97) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:127) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:113) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/internal/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform from [Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 24 more

13:13:20,997 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([]): java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014670: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.jpa
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:99) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:601) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:479) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:283) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:278) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:268) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:291) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:346) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:321) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:253) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform (Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:91) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform (Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.injectJtaManager(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.loadPersistenceAdapterModule(PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.subsystem.JPAExtension.initialize(JPAExtension.java:110)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:97) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:127) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:113) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/internal/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform from [Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @55308275 (finder: local module finder @63c4fb04 (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 24 more

13:13:21,005 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
13:13:21,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-4) stopped in 41ms
```